# I have multiple users, can i lock the web page so that only one user at a time can update a record?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, t-sql

Can anyone help or provide me with some suggestions for the below query.

I have a web form (Minutes of Meeting) and 8 users that need to access this web page and update their area.  A user may have more than one area to update and essentially i would like to some how lock down the web page if possible when a user is using it so that no other user can update this web page till joe bloggs has finished with it.

I have a Active Directory security group set up to restrict the site to that group of users only, but i need to think of a solution to the above?

Is there a way i can do this via a web control or via SQL?

Comment: In the page Load event you could set a boolean the page is active.  If the page is active then make it read only.  In the page Upload event set it to unactive.  Problem you have there is if someone leaves the page up then it is locked.  Or if the Unload event does not fire then you have a locked page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be better ways to do it. However, Is it possible for you to introduce a sql table column  similar to "UpdateInProgress" (bit). Any update process sees that column, If 0 then It updates to 1 and after It saves the changes and updates back to 0 so that the form is available for other to update. If update process sees 1, It can't update the web form because update is in progress.

I also suggest to introduce another column named "UpdateInProgressBy" to check who has opened it for editing.

Comment: This may be a suitable option for me to complete.  I already have my SQL and Stored procedures set up in place.  In not really that familiar with Javascript but im sure I can work it out using SQL.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all we must note that there is a big time from the moment the user reads the data, get it in a page, change them and then try to write them back. So we are not talking for the `lock` command on SQL, nether any other lock that happens in milliseconds and help to synchronize threads, but here we must synchronize people and what they write.

There is also a problem if the user leave the page for any reason and this can make the data lock for ever.

This problem can solve with two approaches.

**the easy one**, when a user try to save data you must check if the same data have been change in the middle, and warn him, or show a merge dialog, or merge programmaticall, or something similar - I do not know what you won.

**the difficult way** is to constantly monitor the page that read and change the data, and keep this monitor results on a common table in the data base, and there if a user have been and stay on page, the rest users get a warning and read only data, until the user go.

This monitor must be made with javasript and must know even if a user abandon the page.

Answer (score 0):

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL as `SERIALIZABLE`

for more information check this link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx